# Angular directive with $watch to set field error on specific value

Tags: angularjs

I have a  field that I want to fail validation if the value is not an integer. there is another field that can update the value of this field so I need to write a directive that will watch the field value the set the validation error whenever the value is changed to something besides an int.

Whenever the 'my-required' attribute is added to the HTML the select options don't load and the directive obviously doesn't work.

question: how do I make this work?

here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zFeGN/2/

html:

```
<select ng-model="tran.type" name="tranType" ng-init="tran.type='1'" ng-options="obj.value as obj.text for obj in tradeTypeOptions" my-required="tran.type"></select>
```

directive:

```
.directive('myRequired', function() {
  var regex = /^\-?\d*$/;
  return {
    restrict: 'A',      
    scope: {
      'myRequired': '='
    },
    link: function(scope, elm, attrs, ctrl) {     
      scope.$watch('myRequired', function(n, o){
        //alert(n);
        if (regex.test(n)) {
          ctrl.$setValidity('myRequired', true);
        } else {
          ctrl.$setValidity('myRequired', false);
        }
      },true);
    }
  };
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to set validity of input, you must use

```
require: 'ngModel'
```

I think you also don't need an isolated scope. And, since `tran.type` is a primitive, you don't need a third parameter of `$watch` set to `true`. Finally, here is a modified directive:

```
.directive('myRequired', function() {
  var regex = /^\-?\d*$/;
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, elm, attrs, ctrl) {
      scope.$watch(attrs.myRequired, function(n, o){
        //console.log(n);
        if (regex.test(n)) {
          ctrl.$setValidity('myRequired', true);
        } else {
          ctrl.$setValidity('myRequired', false);
        }
      });
    }
  };
});
```

And a working jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/aM84a/2/

Comment: the $watch allows for the validation even if it is updated by another action or directive(ie. not user input). That is what happens in my use case. I thought i needed to define scope to isolate the <select> so i could reuse the directive on other fields but evidently, that just isolates the scope and overrides the parent scope which is why the select values weren't loading. thanks for the help.

Comment: This directive can be reused on multiple elements (with different models of course) too. See here: http://jsfiddle.net/aM84a/5/

Answer (score 0):

You need to require the controller.

```
.directive('myRequired', function() {
  var regex = /^\-?\d*$/;
  return {
    restrict: 'A',      
    scope: {
    'myRequired': '='
    },
    controller : 'ControllerName', // require the controller
    link: function(scope, elm, attrs, ctrl) {   
       // ctrl was never injected...
    }
}
```